# High-Pass Filter Setup

Tags: circuit-design, oscilloscope, passive-networks

In several designs I've come across the following setup. Design -> RC Network (High Pass) -> Oscilloscope Input:

[image]

Where SK2 is the SMA connector from the PCB that goes into an oscilloscope.

Some questions:

1. What is the purpose for having two RC networks? I can understand that the 2.2uF cap will allow frequencies above 1.45kHz (fc= 1/(2πRC)) and the 100nF cap will allow 31.85kHz. But why not just use the 100nF cap? Is there some limitations that the 100nF cap would normally have that would require a 2.2uF cap?
2. Or am I mistaken and this is actually just a simple RC circuit where the time constant t=RC is the importance of this setup?
3. If the latter is true, why would you need an RC network before an oscilloscope input? I understand you need 50ohm resistor for impedance matching, but then why the capacitors?

Comment: Where did the circuit come from - I suspect that it isn't as common as you might think and that there might be another purpose to this.

Comment: In this case, it's just measuring transistor switching characteristics at relatively high current (10-30A).